# Difference between Places API and Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I was using Places API in my android app, recently Google said it's going to deprecate so I migrated to new version, but now it's decreasing from my credit (see attached image).
What is difference between Places API & Place API for Android?
I found Place API for Android is free and it's not charging me.
Is the latter one still active or it's going to deprecate?

Generally how can I have **Google Places Auto Complete** for free?

[image]

Comment: You can have a free 300$ credits by attaching your card. so first 300 credits are free

Comment: @MabKiani I know about free credit, but I have lots of users.

Comment: Then you have to buy it because now nothing is free. just the first 300 credits are free then you have to pay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Google has revised their pricing for Places API. Now nothing is free**

First up, I hope you know that you can bump your Places API quota from 1,000 queries/day up to 100,000 queries/day just by verifying your identity? This doesn't cost anything. And if even 100,000 QPD are not enough, you can purchase a [Google Places API for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview) license.

But to actually answer your question, I'm not aware of any alternative that's both good and unlimited. The main competitors with worldwide coverage are:

- [Foursquare Venues](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues.html), which is limited to 5,000 queries/hour. [Here's a
  lengthy point-by-point comparison](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-each-%E2%80%98places%E2%80%99-API-ie-Foursquare-versus-Google) of the two.
- Factual's [Global Places](https://www.factual.com/products/global-places/), limited to 10,000 queries/day.

Comment: 100,000 free queries per day? Awesome!! Would you please give me a link to this?

Comment: i have added a link in my answer